# make Video Private and add Preformatted Title using VimeoUpload

Tags: ios, vimeo, vimeo-ios

I'm using VimeoUpload by Alfie Hanssen: https://github.com/alfiehanssen

I need my app to set the videos to either private or password protected.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @user3634131 for posting,

You can set the video privacy value, this is supported by VimeoUpload. Please review the [README](https://github.com/vimeo/VimeoUpload) file for instructions. You can also check out the [VideoSettings](https://github.com/vimeo/VimeoUpload/blob/v0.9/VimeoUpload/Upload/Model/VideoSettings.swift) class. See here for a [list of privacy values](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/endpoints/videos#/%7Bvideo_id%7D) that you can pass in.

You can specify your video's title (see links above) but not the actual file name on the Vimeo servers. You can of course control the local file name if you wish, that's totally up to you.

Comment: Hi. I very much appreciate that you are helping with questions concerning what seems to be your product. It is also appropriate to link to additional info which is helpful for the question. Strictly speaking, to the point of nitpicking, your answer could be considered link only (because it only states directly here, i.e. not in links, *that* it can be done, but not *how*). Could you give the shortest summary of the solution directly here please? Maybe just name the config option or API which supports it. To me only naming the related class seems a little short.

Comment: Equally nitpicky, please simply state explicitly that it is your product.

Comment: My comments are nitpicky. I did not and will not vote or close-vote or flag. or anything negative. I only want to help you avoid that others do. And as soon as I notice a corresponding edit I will delete my comments. Thanks for helping with your product here and have fun.